# How do you say them with the implication that it's one or the other?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> An angel and demon appeared and they tried to convince the man to
> support **them** instead.

Them instead doesn't make sense, so

> An angel and demon appeared and they tried to convince the man to
> support one or the other

One or the other sounds odd, so I am not sure what's the correct wording for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the word **each** to make it clear that they are arguing individually, not on the same side.

> An angel and demon appeared and **each [one]** tried to convince the man to support them.

This is a case where the *gender-neutral singular "they"* gets in the way of the meaning of the sentence; in Olden Days (like the 1980s or so) you could write

> An angel and demon appeared and each tried to convince the man to support **him**.

where "him" refers to the angel and the demon as individuals.

Comment: How come they is a gender-neutral singular? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Sayaman: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Answer (score 0):

"Them" actually does make sense to an extent. In novels and in speech, pronouns are used to avoid redundancy.

However, some information is missing, who are the angels trying to convince the man not to follow? What's the name of the man? If you filled in these details, it would be less vague. For example: "An angel and demon appeared before Tom, and they tried to convince the man to support them instead of mankind."